# Private AWS credentials being shared with Serverless.com?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, serverless, serverless.com

I've been having trouble with a deployment with a serverless-component, so I've been trying to debug it. Stepping through the code, I actually thought I'd be able to step into the component itself and see what was going on.

[image]

But to my surprise, I couldn't actually debug it, because the component doesn't actually exist on my computer. Apparently the serverless cli is sending a request to a server, and the request seems to include everything serverless needs to build and deploy the actual service— which includes my AWS credentials...

Is this a well-known thing? Is there a way to force serverless to build and deploy locally? This really caught me be surprise, and to be honest I'm not very happy about it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used their platform, (I thought the CLI only executed from your local seems very risky), but you can make this more secure by the following:

First setup an `iam` role which can only do the deploy actions for your app. Then make a profile which assumes this role when you work on your serverless app and  use the cli.

Secondly you can also avoid long-term cli credentials (iam users) by using the AWS SSO functionality which generates cli credentials for an hour, and with the AWS cli, you can login from the cli I believe. What this will mean is that your CLI credentials will live for at maximum 1 hour.

If the requests are always coming from the same IP you can also put that in an IAM policy but I wouldn't imagine there is any guarantee that their IP will always be the same.